# Air for iOS - Debug app without developer certificate

Tags: ios, air, flash-cs6

Is it possible to debug an AIR for iOS app without an Apple developer certificate or do I need a jailbreaked device for that? (I'm using Flash CS6 and Air 3.5 on Windows XP)

Thank you. Uli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible anymore with stock devices.